# Solve equation with log factor inside exp

Tags: logarithms

I'm sure this is trivial. I want to reform the basis of a logarithm, so that I transform a factor

```
10.0/log(10.0)
```

into a factor

```
1.0/log(x)
```

so I want to solve x in

```
1.0/log(x) = 10.0/log(10.0)
```

I reciprocate and exponentiate

```
x = exp(log(10.0)/10.0)
  = exp(log(10.0)) - exp(10.0)  // ?
  = 10.0 - exp(10.0)
```

But this is wrong; it yields -22016.465 instead of the empirical result 1.258926.

---

Ok, the answer seems to be $\sqrt[10]{10}$. But why?

Comment: $\exp(a/b)$ is not $\exp(a) - \exp(b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you made a mistake when you converted $e^{\frac{\ln 10}{10}}$ into $e^{\ln 10}-e^{10}$. This is incorrect; exponents don't work that way like logarithms do.

Instead, what you should do is notice that

$$\frac{\ln 10}{10}=\frac{1}{10} \ln 10=\ln({10^\frac{1}{10}})=\ln \sqrt[10]{10}$$

and then you have

$$e^{\frac{\ln 10}{10}}=e^{(\ln \sqrt[10]{10})}=\sqrt[10]{10}$$